# jquery: load/include html code into html file without delay?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a mobile-app that uses cordova, so it's basically a html-website runing in an app. And I have a lot of elements and html-code that has to be present on all pages, e.g. navigation but also popups and so on and so on.

While working on larger webprojects I usually wrap these kind of code-segments in php-files and use "php include" to create my html file. Here however I can't work with php since there is no server. So since I would like to avoid having countless copies of the same code in every html-file, I'm looking for a way to include html code into an html file using jquery maybe?

I did try it with:

```
$("#includeContent1").load( "mod_navigation.html" );
```

and

```
$.get('mod_navigation.html', function(data) { $('body').append(data);});
```

Both worked, not as great as php, but did the trick. Problem is, the additional content (in this case the navigation) is being loaded "after" the parent html file is shown, making the navigation just pop up with a slight delay. This looks just horrible, because the navigation at the bottom of the screen just keeps flickering while using the app.

Is there a way to avoid these delays? Maybe by jumping to the new page AFTER everything in the html file has been loaded ... or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

could you just try to create the whole DOM in a variable, and when all the HTML code is saved in the variable append it to the body? Say

```
$("body").empty(); // clear all
var content = "";
/* start to create content here */
$("body").append(content);
```

Althoug I have no idea how fast this is...

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use JavaScript that's on your page to preprocess that page's HTML as it is part of the document and therefore by definition executed after the document has been loaded.
You could however use a callback function to only display the new page after it has fully been loaded.